# Why does the Google Play Games login fail in the unpublished version of my game?

Tags: google-play-games

I have working Google Play Game leaderboards and achievements in my game. They work perfectly fine when the game is installed from the play store, but when I install the apk on my phone to test(from the computer), Google Play Games fails to login my account, and of course, the leaderboards and achievements don't load. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution! It's pretty simple. I did two things:

1. To fix a leaderboard error where it wouldn't load on an unpublished of my game, I went to Google Play Console and clicked on Game Services. I clicked on my game and went to leaderboards. Then, I disabled tamper protection. That solves that error. It's so obvious but it took me so long to figure it out.
2. To be able to login to google play games on my unpublished version of my game, I went to Game Services, clicked on Game Details and scrolled down to where it says API Console Project. Clicked on the link that took me to APIs and Services. Clicked on Credentials, created a new oAuthClient and pasted my SHA1 that's under App Signing on Google Play Console. So now, I have two oAuthClients for my one game that work for both the published and unpublished version of my game.

Hope this helps anyone!